# sendRequest() from javascript to action class in struts 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2

I want to call an action on selection of s:select

**jsp snippet:**

```
 <s:select list="stateList" 
   name="customerBean.state" 
   onchange="fetchCity()" 
   onselect="fetchCity()" 
   headerKey="0" 
   headerValue="Select"  
   cssClass="form-control" 
   id="state" 
   class="form-control" 
   placeholder="State here" 
   cssErrorClass="form-control is-invalid">
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fetchCity() {

            console = document.getElementById('console');
            var selectBox = document.getElementById('state');
            var selectedIndex = selectBox.selectedIndex;
            var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectedIndex].value;
             alert("AjaxRetrieveUser.action?stateName=" + selectedValue);
            sendRequest("AjaxRetrieveUser.action",
                    "stateName=" + selectedValue, "POST");
        }
```

The problem is its not calling action.
If I call action directly to web browser like `http://localhost:8084/IACMS/iacms/jsp/ltr/AjaxRetrieveUser.action?stateName=Washington` then action gets called. Please help.

Comment: Is anything in the JS and/or network consoles?

Comment: No. I have removed line console = document.getElementById('console'); from function. still not working. Alert box is shown. Do you know what should be the context path for calling action from JS?